# Navigation to pages in subfolders in JSF 2 does not work

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2.2

I'm having the following problem: I have a folder hierarchy where I separate my project web pages:

```
Web
 |- Acoes
 |   |- usuariosAcoes.xhtml
 |   |- cadastrarAcao.xhtml
 |- usuarios
 |   |- listarUsuarios.xhtml
 |   |- cadastrarUsuario.xhtml
```

But when I try to navigate the ManagedBean the pages do not load, only updates the current page if I try to access a page that is outside of the current page folder.

For example, if I am in listarUsuarios.xhtml page and I try to access the page via ManagedBean cadastrarUsuario.xhtml everything works:

```
public String acessaCadastro(){ return "cadastrarUsuario"; }
```

But if I'm on page list Usuarios.xhtml and try to access usuariosAcoes.xhtml that is in another folder, nothing happens, only reloads the page I already am:

```
public String acessarAcoesUsuario(){ return "usuariosAcoes"; }
```

I tried so but did not solve:

```
public String acessarAcoesUsuario(){ return "Acoes/usuariosAcoes"; }
```

so not:

```
public String acessarAcoesUsuario(){ return "../Acoes/usuariosAcoes"; }
```

and even then:

```
public String acessarAcoesUsuario(){ return "Acoes/usuariosAcoes.xhtml"; }
```

or:

```
public String acessarAcoesUsuario(){ return "../Acoes/usuariosAcoes.xhtml"; }
```

So how do I solve this issue? Remembering that not use the faces-config.xml to create routes since the JSF 2.x already abstracts it.

Comment: Work with "*context path*" instead. (For a pure technical standpoint, navigation rules in `faces-config.xml` are not obsolete, by the way).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand, I has the same problem 4 days ago.

When you use action in an button for navigate to another page, the button only render the target page in your current page.

I use this solution:

```
public void navigateTo(String href) {
        try {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("MYSERVERADDRESS" + href);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
    }
}
```

In your action, you can use "navigateTo("page.xhtml")" insted of returning address to Action of Button.

```
public String acessarAcoesUsuario(){
    navigateTo("/Acoes/usuariosAcoes.xhtml");
    return "";
}
```

or simply

```
public void acessarAcoesUsuario(){
    navigateTo("/Acoes/usuariosAcoes.xhtml");
}
```